# PHP a loop takes a second longer to run if there are calls in it to methods from the same object regardless of how many

Tags: php, performance

The code I am using to cause this is too big to post here, and the problem is so odd that I can't recreate a smaller example that has the same issue. I have some code that looks roughly like this:

```
<?php
class A {

    //Lots of methods

    public function fastMethod($id) {
        return 0;
    }

    public function differentFastMethod($id) {
        $this->someOtherObject->someOtherFastMethod();
        return $this->fastMethod($id);
    }

    public function slowMethod() {
        $c = 0;
        $start = microtime(true);
        // hugeList has about 100,000 ids.
        foreach ($this->hugeList as $id) {
            // bigLookupTable has an array for almost all ids, each array contains one or two items.
            if (isset($this->bigLookupTable[$id]) {
                foreach ($this->bigLookupTable[$id] as $differentId) {
                    fastMethod($diferentId);
                    $c++;
                }
            }
        }
        $end = microtime(true);
        print $end - $start;
    }
}

?>
```

running `slowMethod` takes about 1 second, but if I delete the call to `fastMethod` it takes about 0.1 second. I thought it must just be big function call overhead, but there's more to it than that.

If I change the call to `fastMethod` with one to `differentFastMethod` for instance, it takes about the same time, even though that not only adds more function calls to this object, but includes some to other objects. Furthermore, if I add more calls to `fastMethod` in the inner loop, each one only adds about another 0.1 seconds to the time. It seems like this loop takes an extra second to run just based on whether or not it calls instance methods on itself, whatever those methods do and however many there are.

Another interesting thing about the performance is the inner loop in `slowMethod`. The arrays passed to it are mostly 1 element long or occasionally 2 elements, so taking out the loop and just calling `fastMethod` on the first item of the array should be about as fast, but this is actually much faster, speeding it up by about the same amount that removing the call to `fastMethod` does.

I realise its hard to diagnose without a working example, but I am stumped as to what could posibly cause behaviour like this, if anyone had any ideas I could test them on the real code.

Comment: Anytime I run in to something like this, I just keep narrowing the scope of what I am timing. So for example -- have you timed "fastMethod" (internal to the function)? Have you created a log, that logs the time right before called fastMethod, as well as the time when the function starts (effectively getting the "overhead" time)?

Comment: I've tried timing these things but just running the function once is very fast and the error in the timing at this level is probably very significant so just multiplying it by 100,000 wouldn't yield an accurate estimate I don't think.

Comment: You don't have "$this->" in front of the call to fastMethod (like you do for the other class calls). If you have a public function called fastMethod too... you may be calling a function different than the one you think you are calling.

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately that's just a transcrption error, it's not in the real code.